# JTree valueChanged event gets called before focusLost of another component on clicking a node

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextfield, jtree

I have a JTree where each node of the tree represents some user data. The data is editable and is stored in a file/db. There are a bunch of JTextField that lets you edit/update the user data for the node. Saving of the data event is fired when JTextField loses the focus. This works fine except when you change the selection of the node in JTree. Because valueChanged of JTree event occurs before focusLost of JTextField.

Here is a SSCCE: http://pastebin.com/wH1Veqdc

```
public class JTreeFocusTest extends JFrame{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public JTreeFocusTest() {
                super("JTree Focus Test");
                JPanel panel = new JPanel(true);
                panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
                MyTree tree = new MyTree();
                panel.add(tree);
                panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));
                panel.add(new MyTextField(tree));
                panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));
                panel.add(new JTextField(30));
                getContentPane().add(panel);
                setVisible(true);
                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                pack();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
                new JTreeFocusTest();
        }
}

class MyTree extends JTree{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public MyTree() {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new MyNode("Root", "Root"));
                DefaultMutableTreeNode child1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new MyNode("Child 1", "DOC122122"));
                root.add(child1);
                DefaultMutableTreeNode child2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new MyNode("Child 2", "DOC134342"));
                root.add(child2);
                DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(root, true);
                setModel(model);
                getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
                setSelectionPath(getPathForRow(0));
        }
}

class MyTextField extends JTextField implements FocusListener, TreeSelectionListener{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private MyTree tree;
        public MyTextField(MyTree tree) {
                this.tree = tree;
                setText("Some");
                addFocusListener(this);
                this.tree.addTreeSelectionListener(this);
                Dimension dim = new Dimension(200, 20);
                setPreferredSize(dim);
                setMaximumSize(dim);
                setMinimumSize(dim);
        }
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {System.out.println("TextField gained focus");}
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                getSelectedNodeUserObj().setValue(getText());
        }
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
                setText(getSelectedNodeUserObj().getValue());
        }
        private MyNode getSelectedNodeUserObj(){
                return ((MyNode)((DefaultMutableTreeNode)this.tree.getSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent()).getUserObject());
        }
}

class MyNode{
        private String label = "";
        private String value = "";

        public MyNode(String label, String value) {
                this.label = label;
                this.value = value;
        }
        public void setValue(String value){
                this.value = value;
        }
        public String getValue(){
                return value;
        }
        public String toString(){
                return label;
        }      
}
```

In this example I just have one field but in the actual application I have several fields that represents user data. Also JTextField is just an example, the input field could be JComboBox or JSpinner.

How can I save this user data? I'd appreciate any help/pointer.

Thanks!

Comment: Post the code here, not on pastebin.

Comment: Its long to paste here. I thought it would be inconvenient because sometimes it makes the question hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because valueChanged of JTree event occurs before focusLost of
>   JTextField.

- this is logical ordering, don't to change that, one `JComponents focusGained`, then after focus owner `focusLost` in the Focus in Window
- `Focus` is quite asyncronous, for `JTextComponent` can be delayed events firing from added `Listeners/InputMask/Formatter`, can be solved by delaying in `invokeLater`, forgot about that, not your issue
- (I'm ...) remove `TreeSelectionListener` from `JTextField`, move to (logical) `JTree`,
- add `System.out.println(getText());`, as 1st code line to `public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {`, see whats happend :-), there is place to store (use `Runnable#Thread`, `SwingWorker` to redirect whatever to `Workers Thread`)
- then there stays question whats happend if value is/are changed in JTextField and user click to the same node, then value stays unchanged or JComponent are refreshed with original value, but this is about bussines logics, not about how to code, my speculation

Comment: 1. The order of events are-> JTree.valueChanged > JTextField.focusLost > JTree.focusGained. How can valueChange occur for JTree without gaining focus? Perhaps, I am not following. 2. TreeSelectionListener is actually in JTree in the application, Just to put together SSCCE I put it in JTextField. 3. Can you please explain it more? I do get the text I need there but I lose the selection i.e. the node. 4. If I resolve the problem where focusLost  of JTextField always gets fired before anything in JTree, it would resolve the problem.

Comment: not focusLost can be initialized from focusGained, then JTrees selection caused focusGained, please don't to change ordering of event, cand be fragille, breakable, (because) I'm sure that is possible to create code for two JComponents that swapping Focus in Window, theory is in my post where Focus is programatically added to JComponents added to util.List, don't thinking about, because not sure, what happened in tha case that is added DocumentListener (Filter), inputmask, formatter, caused long loop for JComboBox & JSpinner and JTextField (where is used JTextComponent as Editor)